# work stealing with Parallel Computing Toolbox

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I have implemented a combinatorial search algorithm (for comparison to a more efficient optimization technique) and tried to improve its runtime with `parfor`.

Unfortunately, the work assignments appear to be very badly unbalanced.

Each subitem `i` has complexity of approximately `nCr(N - i, 3)`.  As you can see, the tasks `i < N/4` involve significantly more work than `i > 3*N/4`, yet it seems MATLAB is assigning all of `i < N/4` to a single worker.

Is it true that MATLAB divides the work based on equally sized subsets of the loop range?

> No, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9937200/103167) cites the documentation saying it does not.

Is there a convenient way to rebalance this without hardcoding the number of workers (e.g. if I require exactly 4 workers in the pool, then I could swap the two lowest bits of `i` with two higher bits in order to ensure each worker received some mix of easy and hard tasks)?

I don't think a full "work-stealing" implementation is necessary, perhaps just assigning `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` to the workers, then when `4` completes first, its worker begins on item `5`, and so on.  The size of each item is sufficiently larger than the number of iterations that I'm not too worried about the increased communication overhead.

Answer (score 5):

If the loop iterations are indeed distributed ahead of time (which would mean that in the end, there is a single worker that will have to complete several iterations while the other workers are idle - is this really the case?), the easiest way to ensure a mix is to randomly permute the loop iterations:

```
permutedIterations = randperm(nIterations);
permutedResults = cell(nIterations,1); %# or whatever else you use for storing results

%# run the parfor loop, completing iterations in permuted order
parfor iIter = 1:nIterations
    permutedResults(iIter) = f(permutedIterations(iIter));
end

%# reorder results for easier subsequent analysis
results = permutedResults(permutedIterations);
```

Comment: Or perhaps with `mod` instead of `randperm`: assuming `nIterations` is a multiple of `n Workers`, use `permutedIterations = reshape(reshape(1:nIterations,nWorkers,[]).',1,[])`